# What is the procedure to make code like Java Editors do, they make keywords of different colors and statements of different color

Tags: java, string, swing, awt

what is the way or logic to make code like java Editors do, the make keywords red and other statements black, i want to make the java code for it.any help will be appreciable.

Comment: i had tried JTextPane, but failed

Comment: (1) Recognize the keywords, and (2) colour them. (2) is the easy part.

Comment: I guess the first step in the whole process starts with understanding [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) in a good way. Depending on the string literals, you colour them against their category.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax Highlighting: How Does Eclipse Do It So Fast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243409/syntax-highlighting-how-does-eclipse-do-it-so-fast)

Comment: as the above link conveyed me something, which in turn tells that it is not that much easy as i was thinking, I am still got fumbled while studying AST, but thank you for your answer friend.

Answer (score 1):

I guess they use an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Comment: can you throw some light on Abstract Syntax Tree please?.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JEditorPane`. This is excellent tools to make your keyword color as well as HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need a component which shows HTML string. Some strings, which you consider "java keywords" are taking "blue keyword css style" and others ( static variables) bold style and so on. A long ways to do it, start with an open-source IDE and see it.